# jQuery - Cannot read property 'IsValid' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply some JS to a form (Gravity Forms) on a WordPress webpage. When I write `console.log( window.objinput_5_9.IsValid() );` in the browser console, I get True or False which is what is expected, however, when I add it to a JS file I get the error

> Cannot read property 'IsValid' of undefined

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    console.log( window.objinput_5_9.IsValid() );
});
```

Comment: Probably because your JS file is running before the variable has been set. That's a guess though, as there's not enough context in the question to answer it.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rory McCrossan suggested, the JS code was running before the variable had been set on the page so I had to add a check to make sure it existed before running the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  // check every 2 seconds to see if the variable exists
  let checkExist = setInterval(function () {
    if ($("#input_5_9").length) {
      // if it does exist do the below
      console.log(window.objinput_5_9.IsValid());
    }
  }, 2000);
});
```